# Why Can't I Say: val list = properties.map((key,value) -> "$key = $value")

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I can say

```
//sweet
for ((key,value) in System.getProperties())
    println("$key = $value")
```

but I cannot say

```
//sour
val properties = System.getProperties()
val list = properties.map((key,value) -> "$key = $value")
```

What is the Kotlin equivalent to `properties.map{case (key, value) => s"$key = $value"}` in Scala?

Comment: are you asking a question on Kotlin or on Scala?

Comment: There is a Kotlin feature that is planned but will not be available in 1.0 which will allow writing `{(key,value) -> "$key = $value"}` to unpack a value type like a `Pair`

Comment: Sorry, I was asking a Kotlin question. Stack Overflow recommended I add the Scala tag, so I agreed, but I can see that was just confusing, even though I started the question with "In Kotlin I can say"

Comment: This is mentioned here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/03/kotlin-m11-is-out/ under the section "Lambda Syntax Restricted (for future enrichment)"

Comment: The wording is still not clear this is asking for kotlin.  Can you change the last sentence to:  What is the Kotlin equivalent to Scala's `properties.map{case (key, value) => s"$key = $value"}`?

Answer (score 7):

In Kotlin 1.0 you can say:

```
val properties = System.getProperties()
val list = properties.map { "${it.key} = ${it.value}" }
```

And if you prefer to unpack the map entries to separate values you can say:

```
val properties = System.getProperties()
val list = properties.map { val (key, value) = it; "$key = $value" }
```

---

In Kotlin 1.1 "you can now use the [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) syntax to unpack the arguments passed to a lambda" ([What's New in Kotlin 1.1 - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html)):

```
val properties = System.getProperties()
val list = properties.map { (key,value) -> "$key = $value" }
```

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find any documentation (like a wiki page or YouTrack issue) stating that such is planned but it wouldn't surprise me if it is. I think it would make sense.

Comment: This is mentioned here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/03/kotlin-m11-is-out/ under the section "Lambda Syntax Restricted (for future enrichment)"

Answer (score 2):

Your question has absolutely nothing with inference.

In scala you doc:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
val properties = System.getProperties()
val list = properties.map{case (key,value) => s"$key = $value"}
```

As for your comments.

> Having gone from years of Scala, to now exploring Kotlin, I tend to like Kotlin better in its power and simplicity, however, it would be nice to be able to infer things better, given that I am still in learning mode.

The issues in your code have nothing to do with type inference. Not even the syntax was right.

Comment: That kind of snarky answer is one of the reasons I have given up on the Scala community. Hopefully the Kotlin community will be more civil.

Comment: This answer should be removed, it is for the wrong language of the question.

Comment: That's the answer for the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your syntax for lambda expressions and unpacking:

```
val properties = mapOf(1 to "First", 2 to "Second")
val list = properties.map {val (value, key) = it; "$key = $value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is a Kotlin feature that is planned but will not be available in 1.0 which will allow writing {(key,value) -> "$key = $value"} to unpack a value type like a Pair – cypressious

Thanks @cypressious that was exactly what I was hoping for. Basically the answer is that Kotlin is still evolving and people are still getting around to polishing off cool stuff.

For now I have found that

```
//savory
val properties = System.getProperties()
val list = properties.map {property -> "${property.key} = ${property.value}"}
```

comes pretty close.

Comment: This is mentioned here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/03/kotlin-m11-is-out/ under the section "Lambda Syntax Restricted (for future enrichment)"